# Put break in loop for reddit scraping code

Tags: python, reddit

I am looking to get all reddit comments between certain dates via python. The below code is what I am trying and it begins at a start_time (= int(dt.datetime(2020,5,1,0,0).timestamp())) but it is not breaking when it reaches the end_time (=end_time = int(dt.datetime(2020,4,20,0,0).timestamp())) of the first of April.

Does anyone know how to update it to cause the loop to break when it reaches this end_time?

```
submission_df = pd.DataFrame(None, columns=["id", "title", "score",
           "author", "author_flair_text", "body", "total_awards_received", "awarders", 
           "created_utc", "full_link", "num_comments"
                                           ])
values = []
def downloadFromUrl(df, object_type):
    count = 0
    previous_epoch = int(start_time) #change this to just start_time?
    if len(values) > 0:
        previous_epoch = values[-1]['created_utc'] - 1
    print(f"Saving {object_type}s")


    while True:
        new_url = url.format(object_type, subreddit) + str(previous_epoch)
        json = requests.get(new_url)
        try:
            json_data = json.json()
        except:
            print(json)
        else:
            if 'data' not in json_data:
                break
            objects = json_data['data']
            if len(objects) == 0:
                break

            for submission in objects:
                previous_epoch = submission['created_utc'] - 1
                count += 1
                if object_type == 'comment':
                    try:
                        handle.write(str(submission['score']))
                        handle.write(" : ")
                        handle.write(datetime.fromtimestamp(submission['created_utc']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
                        handle.write("\n")
                        text = submission['body']
                        textASCII = text.encode(encoding='ascii', errors='ignore').decode()
                        handle.write(textASCII)
                        handle.write("\n-------------------------------\n")
                    except Exception as err:
                        print(f"Couldn't print comment: https://www.reddit.com{submission['permalink']}")
                        print(traceback.format_exc())

                elif object_type == 'submission':
                    if 'awarders' in submission:
                        awarders = submission['awarders']
                    else:
                        awarders = None
                    if 'total_awards_received' in submission:
                        total_awards = submission['total_awards_received']
                    else:
                        total_awards = None
                    if 'body' in submission:
                        body = submission['body']
                    else:
                        body = None

                    try:
                        values.append(dict(zip(submission_df.columns, [submission['id'], submission['title'], submission['score'], submission['author'],
                                        submission['author_flair_text'], body,
                                        total_awards, awarders, submission['created_utc'],
                                        submission['full_link'], submission['num_comments'], submission['over_18']])))
                    except Exception as err:
                        print(f"Couldn't print post: {submission['url']}")
                        print(traceback.format_exc())
                    
        print(f"Saved {len(values)} of {count} {object_type}s through {datetime.fromtimestamp(previous_epoch).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}")

    print(f"Saved {count} {object_type}s")
    return values
    # handle.close()")
    
new_values = downloadFromUrl(submission_df, "submission")
```

Answer (score 1):

You never modify the objects array after creating it, so its length never changes. Even if you did, you are creating the object inside the loop, so it will always be full.